# Cappuccino - Load images from disk to a CPImageView

Tags: cappuccino, objective-j

I am looking for a way to load an image from my disk into a CPImageView. Is this possible?

Comment: You mean you want to upload an image to a Cappuccino app and have it display? Cappuccino can't receive your upload, you'd have to send it to your server and then you'd display it like you display any image on your server in Cappuccino.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To upload an image to a server, you could either use a normal file upload button such as what is implemented by [`FileUpload`](https://github.com/MCF/FileUpload). Or, if you're not afraid of some potentially very tricky cross browser problems you could try to use my fork of [`Deep Drop Upload`](https://github.com/aljungberg/deepDropUpload/commits/flllow) which allows drag and drop upload.

In either case, once the image is on your server you need your server to return the URL of where the image can be viewed. Let's say this URL is `http://example.com/uploads/image101.png`. Then you can display it in a `CPImageView` the normal way:

```
var imageView = [[CPImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 100, 100)];
[imageView setImage:[[CPImage alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:"http://example.com/uploads/image101.png"]];
```